# NoSuchFieldError when reading Excel sheet in java

Tags: java, xssf, nosuchfieldexception

I've followed a simple guide to constructing a workbook using Apache POI XSSF. Following the same guide I was able to WRITE an Excel sheet, however when attempting to read from one, I'm receiving the error displayed after the code.

Code:

```
try {
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("howtodoinjava_demo.xlsx"));

    // Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

    // Get first/desired sheet from the workbook
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

    // Iterate through each rows one by one
    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
    while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
        Row row = rowIterator.next();
        // For each row, iterate through all the columns
        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

        while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
            Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
            // Check the cell type and format accordingly
            switch (cell.getCellType()) {
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "t");
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "t");
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
    file.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Error output:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError:
>   RAW_XML_FILE_HEADER   at
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.ZipHelper.verifyZipHeader(ZipHelper.java:179)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.ZipHelper.openZipStream(ZipHelper.java:228)
>     at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.(ZipPackage.java:93)
>     at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:294)
>     at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:37)    at
>   org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.(XSSFWorkbook.java:273)
>     at com.wtolliver.spring.test.ReadExcel.readExcel(ReadExcel.java:18)
>     at com.wtolliver.spring.test.App.main(App.java:17)

Comment: Are you sure that the Excel file is in good shape? Looks like it might be corrupted.

Comment: This `NoSuchFieldError` stems mostly from a __version mismatch__ between [apache-poi dependencies](http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/java-lang-NoSuchFieldError-RAW-XML-FILE-HEADER-td5723977.html)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After looking around a bit. I browsed the [documentation for APACHE POI](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/poifs/common/POIFSConstants.html#RAW_XML_FILE_HEADER), and saw that this was one of the constants (not that i know what that really means).

But eventually, I realized all the tutorials I used were pre-2014.

So I just changed my Maven POM to version 3.11 for both dependencies of `apache-poi`, and `poi-ooxml`.

Its working now.

Comment: I suggested an improved formatting and added link to stated docs.

Answer (score 3):

I got same error with different constant:

> Exception in thread "main" `java.lang.NoSuchFieldError`: **RETURN_NULL_AND_BLANK**

Googled lot but no answer. I was using apache `poi-ooxml` version 3.11. Later I changed to version 3.17. Then it was working fine.

Hope this might helpful someone.

Answer (score 1):

In case if anyone working with the latest Apache POI library, make sure you add these dependencies and it works absolutely fine.

```
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- log4j is optional-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Java Snippet:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Demo1 {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Demo1.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File file = new File("File location");
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

            XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
            XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

            Iterator<Row> itr = sheet.iterator();
            logger.info("The given file is");
            while (itr.hasNext()) {
                Row row = itr.next();
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                    switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                        case STRING:
                            logger.info(cell.getStringCellValue());
                            break;
                        case NUMERIC:
                            logger.info(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                            break;
                        default:
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, try changing the XSSFWorkbook diclaration to HSSFWorkbook. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For the following error "java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: RETURN_NULL_AND_BLANK"

Please perform following task: upgrade the APACHE POI 3.** to the latest version in my case i have done the following thing i was previously using the apache poi 3.09 later i have upgraded the lib to latest version i.e 3.12 and its work !!

Perform the following steps and your code will but make sure the error should be same.